# How to layout subviews on device rotation in iOS 10

Tags: ios, rotation, ios10

How to layout subviews on device rotation in iOS 10?

I want to redraw my subview when rotate device.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Add and use `didRotateFromInterfaceOrientation` orientation delegate method.

To layout subviews use `autoresizingMask` property of `UIView`,

Like,

```
YourView.autoresizingMask = UIViewAutoresizingFlexibleWidth | UIViewAutoresizingFlexibleHeight;
```

From the [UIView documentation](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/uikit/reference/uiview_class/uiview/uiview.html#//apple_ref/occ/instp/UIView/autoresizingMask):

> When a view’s bounds change, that view automatically resizes its
>   subviews according to each subview’s autoresizing mask.

Changing `autoresizingMask` to other than `None` will trigger `layoutSubviews`.

So, you can use below code to layout subviews using `didRotateFromInterfaceOrientation` delegate method.

```
-(void)didRotateFromInterfaceOrientation:(UIInterfaceOrientation)fromInterfaceOrientation {

   [self.view layoutIfNeeded];
   [self.view setNeedsLayout];
   self.view.autoresizingMask = UIViewAutoresizingFlexibleWidth | UIViewAutoresizingFlexibleHeight;

   //....Other code
}


-(void)layoutSubviews{

   //write your code to draw here
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Since `didRotateFromInterfaceOrientation` has become deprecated in iOS 9 you should use `viewWillTransition(_:_:)` method.

Here's an example:

```
override func viewWillTransition(to size: CGSize, with coordinator: UIViewControllerTransitionCoordinator) {
    super.viewWillTransition(to: size, with: coordinator)
    coordinator.animate(alongsideTransition: nil, completion: { _ in 
        // called right after rotation transition ends
        self.view.setNeedsLayout()
    })
}
```